# How to use both upright and slanted Greek capitals in mathpazo?

Tags: fonts, mathpazo

The mathpazo package has an slantedGreek option which allows for the use of slanted Greek capitals. However, I would like to use both the slanted and upright version of the Greek capitals. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: `\upGamma`, `\upDelta` and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package `mathpazo` defines `\upGamma`, `\upDelta` and so on to be “fixed” upright Greek letters (not sensible to the change of math group).

Thus

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$\mathbf{\Gamma}\mathbf{\upGamma}$
\end{document}
```

will print only the first `\Gamma` in bold face. With `amsmath` one has `\varGamma`, `\varDelta` and so on for the slanted Greek uppercase letters.

You can use the `slantedGreek` option for having `\Gamma` print a slanted letter and use `\upGamma` for the upright one. However, in this case, `\mathbf{\Gamma}` will still print an upright boldface Gamma.

If you need boldface slanted Greek uppercase, the `bm` package is needed, with `\bm{\Gamma}` (and the `slantedGreek` option, of course).